# Bounding difference of nearby values of a truncated infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to verify some results numerically but I haven't previously worked with truncated infinite series in this way and was wondering if anyone might be able to spare some advice.

Generally, I'm trying to figure out given an infinite series $f(z)=\sum_{m=-L}^\infty c(m)q^m$ where $q=e^{2\pi iz}$ for complex $z$, and a fixed $\epsilon$, how small $\delta$ needs to be and how large $K$ needs to be so that $|z-z'|<\delta$ implies $|f^{[K]}(z)-j^{[K]}(z')|<\epsilon$ where $f^{[K]}(z)=\sum_{m=-L}^K c(m)q^m$ is a truncation of $f(z)$ at the $n=K$ term.

In particular, I'm looking at $j(z) = \sum_{m=-1}^\infty c(m)q^m$ (the j-invariant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) for $z$ in the upper half plane. For $m\geq1$ I have an upper bound $c(m)\leq \frac{e^{4\pi\sqrt{m}}}{m^{3/4}\sqrt{2}}$ on the coefficients.

I've tried playing around with the triangle inequality and can't seem to get rid of dependence on the imaginary part of either $z$ or $z'$:
$|j^{[K]}(z)-j^{[K]}(z')|\leq e^{2\pi P}[e^{-2\pi\delta}+1+\sum_{m=1}^K c(m)(e^{2\pi m\delta}+1)]$ where the $P$ showing up in the first exponential is the imaginary part of $z'$.

I figure there will be many different pairs $(\delta,K)$ that will satisfy this but my main issue is being unsure of how to simultaneously bound them in terms of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Since the series doesn't converge when $z$ is real (at least the given information doesn't force it to), my guess is that there isn't a way to get rid of the dependence on the imaginary part of $z$.